# PHP XML remove element and all children by name

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have an XML file structured as:

```
<root>
  <featured>
    <title></title>
    <tweet></tweet>
    <img></img>
  </featured>
</root>
```

The  element is added dynamically , the user needs the option to remove the  element on certain occasions,

I have tried a few variations of code including:

```
        $featureddel = $xpath->query('//featured');

while ( $featureddel->hasChildNodes()){
$featureddel->removeChild($featureddel->childNodes->item(0));
}
```

which gives me a error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::hasChildNodes()
```

Ive also tried:

```
$featureddel= $dom->getElementsByTagName('featured');
$featureddel->parentNode->removeChild($featureddel);
```

which returns:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function removeChild() on a non-object
```

Comment: Btw the error messages are pretty obvious ;-)

Comment: `$featuredl` isn't a DOM node object, it's a DOMNodeList object, which can be considered an array of nodes, but is not a node itself, so it can't have `childNodes()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `DOMElement::getElementsByTagName` and `DOMXPath::query` return a `DOMNodeList`. Your code seems to be expecting a single `DOMNode` instead. Try this:

```
$featureddel = $xpath->query('//featured');
// OR:
// $featuredde1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('featured');

foreach ($featuredde1 as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

**Edit**: This exact code works as expected for me (PHP 5.3, Debian Squeeze):

```
<?php 
$xml = '<root>
  <featured>
    <title></title>
    <tweet></tweet>
    <img></img>
  </featured>
</root>';    
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$featuredde1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('featured');

foreach ($featuredde1 as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>

</root>
```

Comment: Same with this, I'm sure its something else in my code, but he element remains. Doing a var_dump of $featureddel returns 'object(DOMNodeList)#14 (0) { }' and of $node 'object(DOMElement)#15 (0) { } '

Comment: @BobFlemming: Then you need to post more code. My answer works as expected. See my edit and example code.

Comment: I have no doubt in your code. Thanks for the help, I'll just have to try and untangle my own code.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
foreach ($featureddel as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

You're probably just forgetting that with both `xPath` and `getElementsByTagName` you get a **list** (`DOMNodeList`) of items. That object itself only has a property `$length`, which you can use to determine how many objects are on the list, and function `item($index)`, which returns specified `DOMNode` from the list. `DOMNodeList` is also iteratable through `foreach`.
So besides `foreach` like I wrote above you can also do:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $featureddel->length; $i++) {
    $temp = $featureddel->item($i); //avoid calling a function twice
    $temp->parentNode->removeChild($temp);
}
```

But `foreach` is usually more preferred.

Comment: thanks, this isn't working in my case . The element remains.  Doing a var_dump of $featureddel returns 'object(DOMNodeList)#14 (0) { }' and of $node 'object(DOMElement)#15 (0) { } '

Comment: You probably forgot to `echo $dom->saveXML()` ? or put it to file or wherever you wanted to. If it shows no errors then it surely **is** working.

Comment: thanks,  solved ,I  was actually re-inserting the <featured> further down the code!