# PHP: Remove Button or Input type="button" Tags

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex Remove Images with style tag from Html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772782/regex-remove-images-with-style-tag-from-html)
>   [PHP XML remove element and all children by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731879/php-xml-remove-element-and-all-children-by-name)

How can I remove Button or input type="button" tags in PHP?

```
<button>button_name</button>
```

I want to remove both of  tag and the content inside of it.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: I hope you already know that [you should not parse (X)HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/540162).

Comment: @erisco see, the first comment is what I meant with the "slap down" I mentioned on the other question ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a little more information about your exact goal, that would be helpful. Usually, the PHP is creating the button in the first place, so the easiest thing would be to find where in the script that html is being generated, make sure you are not going to be breaking something critical, and delete it from the php script.

One way of finding the place in the php code where the button is being generated is to do a multi-file find in your IDE or advanced text editor. Try searching for `<button>` and see if you can find the exact button you are trying to eliminate.

By the way, before you delete anything permanently, I highly recommend committing to your version control system, or at least making a manual backup of the file unless you have deleted the wrong thing.

Comment: Just saying, but the question doesn't state that the asker is trying to use regex on html, it just appears that way because of the tags.

Answer (score -1):

To remove  tag you can use :

```
strip_tags($str,"remove","<button>");
```

For more take a look at here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: This is wrong! 1) it won't remove the `input type="button"`, as asked by OP; 2) `string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )`  What are those 3 params you're passing, anyway? Did YOU read how strip_tags work?